# How to let ASCII coded hexadecimals in an array to be treated as hexadecimals and not as characters in a string by Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, ascii

```
In [301]: string_to_write
Out[301]: '0x010x530x380x430x430x330x460x460x300x300x300x300x300x300x310x320x310x0D'

In [302]: len(string_to_write)
Out[302]: 72

In [303]: thestring="\x01\x53\x38\x43\x43\x33\x46\x46\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x31\x32\x31\x0D"

In [304]: print thestring
S8CC3FF000000121

In [305]: len(thestring)
Out[305]: 18
```

I need to use serial port to communicate with a device and I need to write a string to the port. I entered **thestring** through keyboard while I used loop to write each of the hexadecimal characters to **string_to_write**. I need to convert this **string_to_write** into  **thestring**. How do I make Python identify groups of four characters each as a hexadecimal.

Comment: Thank you Iron Fist for your edit.

Comment: Are u using Python2?

Comment: Yes, I am using Python2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to chop `string_to_write` into strings of length 4, convert those strings to integer, then convert each of those integers to characters. Here's an efficient way to do that in Python 2 (a different approach is needed in Python 3). Note that this code assumes that all of your hex codes contain exactly 4 chars, with the leading `0x`. This script also uses `binascii.hexlify` to print the output data in a convenient format.

```
from binascii import hexlify

def hex_to_bin(s):
    return ''.join([chr(int(''.join(u), 16)) for u in zip(*[iter(s)] * 4)])

s2w = '0x010x530x380x430x430x330x460x460x300x300x300x300x300x300x310x320x310x0D'
thestring = "\x01\x53\x38\x43\x43\x33\x46\x46\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x31\x32\x31\x0D"

out = hex_to_bin(s2w)
print repr(thestring)
print repr(out)
print hexlify(out)
print thestring == out
```

**output**

```
'\x01S8CC3FF000000121\r'
'\x01S8CC3FF000000121\r'
01533843433346463030303030303132310d
True
```

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built-in encode lib for example:

```
>>> "hello".encode("hex")
'68656c6c6f'
>>> "68656c6c6f".decode("hex")
'hello'
>>>
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use this as an example:

```
string_to_write = '0x010x530x380x430x430x330x460x460x300x300x300x300x300x300x310x320x310x0D'
temp = [i for i in string_to_write.split('0x') if i]
print map(lambda x: int('0x'+x, 16), temp)
```

op:

```
[1, 83, 56, 67, 67, 51, 70, 70, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 50, 49, 13]
```